# Universal Image Loader can't be decoded the image file

Tags: android, image, universal-image-loader

I implement downloading image app. I used the [universal image downloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for **image caching** only. Sometime the downloading process is not finished due to the connection refused. And I load the  images by the universal image loader after the downloading process.

```
imageLoader.loadImageSync("file:///" + absolute_path + "/" + photo.link);
```

I got the error from universal image loader.

```
12-18 10:55:52.166: E/ImageLoader(29921): Image can't be decoded [file:////data/data/com.../Content/131205-02.jpg_1024x720]
```

I checked the file.

```
File file = new File(absolute_path + "/" + photo.link);
Log.d("Fragment", absolute_path + "/" + photo.link + " file is exist:" + file.exists());
```

In the log cat.

```
12-18 10:55:51.936: D/Fragment(29921): /data/data/com.../Content/131205-02.jpg file is exist:true
```

I would like to know that why image loader cannot be decoded even the file exist.

Comment: Too much slashes. Try `"file://"`.

Comment: yes, I did but same result. IMO, the image file is broken to encode. Am I right?

Comment: How can I know? You didn't provide any logs.

Comment: I checked the image size. The normal image's size is bigger than the broken one.